# href link not working for the first time in email

Tags: java, http, https, httpsession

I have href link which was built on java, I am using it for forget password.

when ever user clicks forget password it asks for email id, user enters email and it sends email with a link where user can enter new password. but this functionality is braking some ware. when I click the link for first time it says session expired it works fine for the second time. Any idea about this problem or anybody faced this kind of problems please reply. Thanks

Comment: Which framework and Web Server are you using? You need to enable unauthenticated access on this page. Your page is checking for session or session check is enabled at the web container level which is throwing the error on first time.

Comment: We are using Websphere Application Server.